# Problem when importing json to dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to import a .json file with pandas.read_json(), but it imports the file as one single line and column.

The structure of the json file is like this:

```
{ "DataList": [ [ { "parameter": 12345, "parmeter 2": 56789, "DataSet": [ {"Data": "data", "Time": "date"} , {...}, {...} ], [ { "parameter": 12345, "parmeter 2": 56789, "DataSet": [ {"Data": "data", "Time": "date"} , {...}, {...} ] }
```

Anyone know how to read it correctly?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since json is a flexible format,it is difficult for pandas to represent the structure as table.But we can do it manually.

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_json("temp.json")

for i in range(0,x.shape[0]):
    print(pd.DataFrame(x.iloc[i][0]))
```

---

Output can be something like this

---

parameter parmeter 2         DataSet
0 12345   56789  {'Data': 'data', 'Time': 'date'}]

Answer (score 0):

No problem still it can work fine